# Laravel 5.5 Auth status in session is lost after redirect to custom url (instead of home)

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5

I have a fresh Laravel 5.5 LTS project and I've published the auth feature using `php artisan make:auth` and tested it, it was all working fine. I.e. after successful register/login, I've got the status in session showing the message.

By default, after successful register/login, it redirects you to `/home` but I wanted a different route; i.e. `/account` - so I made the following controller:

**app/Http/Controllers/Account/HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Account;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the account home page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('account.home');
    }
}
```

and Created the following **resources/views/account/home.blade.php** view with:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <!-- Inner Wrapper Start -->
    <section class="inner-wrapper call-back small-section">
        <div class="container">
            <p>Welcome to My Account page</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Inner Wrapper End -->

@endsection
```

and updated the **routes/web.php** like this:

```
// Authentication routes
Auth::routes();

// Account routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'account', 'namespace' => 'Account', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

and finally updated **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php** with the new direct url:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/account';
```

---

Now when I register or login within my app, it's correctly redirecting me to `/account` url, but I am no longer getting the `status` from the session - as if it's getting lost.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: When you had route `/home`, did you get `status`?

Comment: Yes, it was working fine.

Comment: What have you been getting as `session('status')` variable? Where was set that one?

Comment: @Tpojka This is standard laravel auth functionality. I don't understand your question.

Comment: What is output on page from `session('status')`?

Comment: Nothing at the moment, because it isn't working. Before, it used to say successfully registered/logged in etc...

Comment: are you sure you created the HomeContoller under the 
```App\Http\Controllers\Account``` namespace.

Comment: Yes, when I login I am seeing the new view with my html `Welcome to My Account page`